# “Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value” in Swift. (for boolean value)

Tags: ios, swift

I looked at other questions but could not solve my problem.

Also, this code line crash in firebase crashlytics.

How can I fix? Thanks.

```
if AUserDefaults.read(key: UDKeys.local_token.rawValue) != nil {
    if !BTSingleton.sharedInstance.isContractVersionCheckRequired {
        getMyShipments()
    }
}
```

[Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Fv6J.png)

Comment: What is `isContractVersionCheckRequired` in `BTSingleton`?  Is it an implicitly unwrapped optional?  You need to at least show the code for that object.

Comment: @Paulw11 You are right, sorry. It is not optional. In BTSingleton: `var isContractVersionCheckRequired : Bool!`

Comment: It is an implicitly unwrapped optional (that is what the ! means). You need to check what is supposed to have assigned a value to that, or make it a true optional or at least conditionally unwrap it to see if it has a value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just need to make sure you have a bool before you read it. I would write it like this because I feel its cleaner:

```
// this approach compares the optional to false so if it is tru or nil it doesn't get executed
    if BTSingleton.sharedInstance.isContractVersionCheckRequired == false {
                getMyShipments()
            }
```

But you could write it like this it may be easier to understand:

```
// this approach safely unwraps the optional and then checks the value
    if let versionCheckRequired = BTSingleton.sharedInstance.isContractVersionCheckRequired, versionCheckRequired == false {
        getMyShipments()
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried your code and the error was cleared.